# How to redirect all urls to a single webpage?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to get all URLs to redirect to index. I have seen answers for doing this in Apache using `.htaccess` or mod_rewrite. Specifically, the following:

```
RewriteEngine On<br>
RewriteBase /<br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d <br>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f <br>
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

However, I am using Tomcat and I keep getting an error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Andy. When people refer to "Apache" it is usually about "Apache httpd web server", which is different product from "Apache Tomcat". Apache Tomcat will ignore `.htaccess`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect All the Pages in Home Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24055314/redirect-all-the-pages-in-home-page)